# Is backtracking considered an heuristic?

Tags: backtracking, heuristics

More specifically, I am trying to figure out if the following statement is correct:

> Every BackTracking is an Heuristic but not every Heuristic is a BackTracking.

Am I right? Cause I feel I am missing something and messing things up.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: I didn't read it anywhere specifically, i am just a little confuse and trying to understand this topic.

Comment: I honestly have never heard (or read) of such a comparison :S And still I find it weird, backtracking is a search action, a heuristic is a function to guide the search. I find little meaning in the statement...maybe smone else will argue

Comment: Thats what i am asking for, if it has no sense it means i am wrong and indirectly it answer my question.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the statement might be true, I'll post an answer as soon as I have some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only question here is: "Is every backtracking a heuristic?"

> Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to SOME computational problems, notably constraint satisfaction problems, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions and abandons each partial candidate as soon as it determines that it cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.

Backtracking should be relatively fast, therefor it is used to determine whether or not a candidate is a valid solution (a rough selection is done). As backtracking obviosly not work with precise solutions, it is definitely a general heuristic method.

Of course, backtracking is not the only metaheuristic principle, so the second part of the sentence does not make sense.